# AjaxToolkit error in asp.net can anyone help me

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious, that you use pre-4.0 .NET Framework. Check minimum [system requirements](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/documentation).